# How gdb find value of all the registers from all the frames in stack

Tags: gdb

While debugging by adding break point, stack frames can  seen by running bt.

On selecting a frame by running info registers, values of registers on a particular frame can be seen.

For example consider breakpoints is set on 5th frame. when break point is hit, going to 3rd frame, one can see view register values.

How does gdb get register values from 3rd frame when break point is set on 5th frame ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It relies on the debug information generated by the compiler to restore (some) register values of the previous frame as part of the stack unwinding process.

http://gnu.wildebeest.org/blog/mjw/2007/08/23/stack-unwinding/

> To help debuggers still get all the information needed to unwind a
>   stack and restore all needed registers the debugging information
>   (DWARF) generated by compilers was extended to include Call Frame
>   Information (CFI) that allows a debugger to reconstruct the calling pc
>   and registers of a function (see the DWARF 3 spec – section 6.4).

For a *relatively* easy to follow DWARF stack unwinding implementation, see [_Unwind_Backtrace()](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libgcc/unwind.inc#l278) in libgcc. This is in-process instead of out of process like GDB.

Comment: Thanks Scott for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

It relies on the **[frame pointer](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_7.html)**, and gets saved register values from the stack.

Comment: Hi Nikolai, Thanks for looking into. From where GDB all the register values ? Frame pointer is for stack frame but gdb shows all the register values.

Comment: Look into stack unwinding info @scottt mentions in his answer. Basically, frame pointer addresses given stack frame where current function preserves values of the registers that might be clobbered by the next call (including frame pointer itself). DWARF debug info describes where they are.